# How do you animate specific objects within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

For Honeycomb or later using FragmentManager I've found many references to using Animation as part of the FragmentTransaction, but how do you animate a view property of the fragment, after the fragment view has been inflated and the fragment attached.

Say you click a button in that fragment and you want to make that button bounce (some kind of tween animation) for example.

Comment: Can't you use the legacy tween animation ? What problem are you facing ?

Comment: I tried objectanimator and several others, which would work fine in an activity, but not allowed in a fragment. I was thinking i should try to stay within a reasonably current framework, but i can't figure out which api set to use. Suggestions are gladly welcome. I'm only finding mostly fragment transaction references to animation.

Comment: There is no difference between animation in a fragment and an activity. You don't animate either of those, you animate the views...and...views are views. Try ... button.animate().scaleX(1.5).setDuration(500).start(); Edit: Of course you can animate not only view properties...but you are giving way to little info to know what you want to animate :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, will try it.  As for giving away too much info, the button was just an example.  I'm actually doing something different with the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ElDuderino, you got me started on the right path.  Finally figured out the more recent method to use from the SDK and had to do the animation programmatically using the following ...

```
anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewobject, "value", 200F);
....
anim.start();
```

The earlier issue I think was due to the fact that I was trying to loadAnimation from XML that seems to  work in a Activity, but isn't supported in a fragment.  I had the same issue across various methods from various API levels. So there may be some slight differences using animation in an activity vs a fragment.